# Are there any Monero devs involved with the LOKI project?

Tags: monero-forks, loki

The Loki project is pretty new, but who is really behind it? Who are the main devs to be able to just fork monero code and build out their own software. The Monero software is pretty complicated, I'd imagine there are Monero devs behind this new system.

Comment: This question seems offtopic for the Monero StackExchange, Please go to one of Loki's social media channels to ask this question

Comment: For better or worse, this site does allow for other cryptonote/fork questions. See https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. However, tewinget is a former Monero contributor, and a current (or recent past) contributor to Loki.